# Is it possible to force DHCPv6 to configure address of a client without DHCP Server?

Tags: ipv6

I'm trying to formulate a way to send Ipv6 address to users in my network

I'm doing a project where I need to mitigate an attack: The scenario is a user is using SLAAC to genarate its adress but the user is being attack by a DOS on DAD so that it would not use the generated IP Address.

I have a approach to detect but do not have a way to mitigate the attack, a way I can give the user Ipv6 Adress.

My first theory is using DHCPv6 packet which I will craft and inject in the network, but I'm not sure if it is possible for a client to accept the packet because it does not have any DHCP Server

Aside from that I do not have any leads or clue on how can I approach the problem

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think this is possible. You always need a client and a server for DHCP(v6). And DHCPv6 should do DAD as well.

Monitoring DAD traffic and talking to the user (or ban him from your network, fire him, ...)   sending it.

Comment: Is there a way I can force a user to get a address? my problem is that there is an attacker who always answer in DAD.

Comment: Static configuration is the only option.

Comment: Static Configuration means I need to tap the router it self right?

Comment: No: The Client. Routers always have to be configured static (with some exceptions).

Comment: Thank You so much for that insight, now I'm thinking if I can't force the user. How can I stop the attacker replying the DAD

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use Secure Neighbor Discovery ? I did not used it until know, but I think you can DAD over the SNDP ? And you can send the SLAAC Router Advertisements over SNDP ?

Or am I wrong ?

Comment: Show me a well known client / sever OS that supports SEND by default and we talk again. Yes you can find a implementations for Linux and there are rumors that some people at the university of Potsdam developed an implementation for Windows but for two years their Website says "not ready for download".

Comment: okay, i don´t know how good These implementations work, but SEND would fix the Problems Franz Justin A. Buenaventura has. But thanks for the hint with University of Potsdam, i will try to contact them.

Comment: http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/meinel/security_tech/ipv6_security/winsend.html - I'm not sure if I would use it. And this is only Windows. What about all the appliances, printers, Linux, MacOSX, ..